# If a particular protein contains 178 amino acids, and there are 367 nucleotides that make up the introns in this gene,

Tags: gene

what is the number of nucleotides that make up the coding and noncoding regions of the gene including the start and stop codons

Comment: where is this question from? is this for homework? can you give any rationale for what you think the answer is?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

178 amino acids => 178 codons =>178 *3 nucleotides => 534 nucleotides for the coding region. Plus 3 nucleotides each for start and stop codon. So the grand total will be (534+367 +6= ) 907 nucleotides